# Do debugging attributes such as [DebuggerDisplay] still get compiled into Release binaries?

Tags: c#, debugging, release-management

Having recently learned of the [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) attribute, I've found it quite useful. However, one thing that surprises me is that it doesn't have a `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` attribute attached to it. Is there some way to force this or is it a bad idea to try? Or does it not matter for some other reason?

Comment: When the DebuggerDisplay attribute is used, does it still get executed in release mode if we don't wrap it in a preprocessor directive? In other words, could it's use in my code slow things down in release mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")] is only used for optimising out method calls.

If you really want to remove these from your builds you can use #ifdef so that the code is only compiled in release mode.

One thing to bear in mind is that you can still debug binaries in release mode, as long as you have the pdb files it shouldn't matter. Release mode just clears up variables sooner and applies some compiler optimisations

Comment: Going farther would there be a way to find out if this information is saved in those .pdb files? If the release "binary" doesn't have them it would be fine.

Comment: It's saved in the dll rather than the pdb file. You can use a tool such as reflector to find this out. PDB files (as a summary) contain the details about the raw source code, line numbers etc

Answer (score 4):

As I often have to debug things in Release configuration builds that don't have the `DEBUG` directive, I would not want these hints to the debugger to be removed.

However, if you have some proprietary or confidential information in the way you display things when debugging that you don't want to make it into your release build, you may want to consider using the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) or [`#if/#elif/#endif`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) preprocessor directives to control what is emitted into your release builds.

For example, you could do:

```
#if DEBUG
[DebuggerDisplay...]
#endif
public class MyAwesomeClass
{
}
```

This would ensure the attribute is only emitted when the DEBUG directive is given.

Answer (score 2):

I'll share a pattern that I've come to appreciate using `partial`.

```
public partial class MyClass{
    //class details here
}
```

And then elsewhere:

```
#if DEBUG
[DebuggerDisplay("DebuggerValue")]
public partial class MyClass{
    //anything needed for debugging purporses
}
#endif
```

This gives the ability to use DebuggerDisplay or other attributes without cluttering-up the base class.

I've been using a handful of files, all wrapped in `#if DEBUG` to hold these Debug-Partials.  It helps keep the core classes cleaner and I don't have to remember to start/end compiler directives for each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be a bad idea, because a lot of times the thing you're attaching the attribute to has some other use besides just showing it in the debugger, IMO.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. I want to compile out the attribute, not the class.